# In Arduino, how do you write to port when port is a variable?

Tags: arduino, embedded

Examples of writing to a port seem to always use the port number as a constant, eg,

```
 OCR2A = 180;
```

How do you write to the port when the port is unknown until run time. For example,

```
int port = (buttonPressed) ? 0x3b : 0x3c;
portWrite( port, 180 );
```

What I cannot find is the funtion `portWrite()`. Does something like that exist?

Comment: Questions about Arduino are more suitable for http://arduino.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know about  arduino.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robert's answer has some imprecise assertions and an incomplete answer.

> Writing directly to port registers you can ruin other settings of the port and sometimes cause permanent damage to controller.

Can ruin other settings: true, you have to know what you are doing (for instance what pins are on the port you are manipulating, and know what are the functions you want to keep.

Can cause permanent damage: not really, or better not because of the port manipulation. If you wire a short circuit to ground and then set it as an output to 1, you can damage it whether you are using the port register or the digitalwrite. You have to be careful in both ways.

Now, returning to your problem, the enumeration is one way, but since the PORTB, PORTC, PORTD are just short name for values, you can set a variable and then use it to indirectly access it.

The type for this kind of variable is a volatile pointer to a byte (volatile means that write and read operations cannot be optimized by the compiler, since the value can change even between two operations):

```
volatile uint8_t *variablePortRegister;
```

You just have to load it with the address (so with the `&` symbol) of the register you want to change:

```
variablePortRegister = &PORTC;
```

then use the pointer to change the value

```
PORTC = 0x12;
            becomes
(*variablePortRegister) = 0x12;
```

This is a short example. For it to work, connect a LED with resistor on arduino pin 5 (bit 5 of PORTD). The LED on the board (labeled L) is connected to pin 13 (bit 5 of PORTB).

The sketch will make one of the two leds blink for five times, then switch to the other. Only port manipulation instructions are used, and you can find that the way to read the port is the same as the one to write it.

```
volatile uint8_t *myportreg;
unsigned long lastTime;
uint8_t counter;

void setup() {
  DDRB |= 0x20;
  DDRD |= 0x20;
  PORTB = 0;
  PORTD = 0;
  counter = 99; // trigger the register change immediately
}

void loop() {
  if (counter >= 10)
  {
    counter = 0;
    if (myportreg == &PORTD)
      myportreg = &PORTB;
    else
      myportreg = &PORTD;
  }
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > 500)
  {
    lastTime = millis();
    // change bit 5 of register
    *myportreg = 0x20 ^ (*myportreg);
    counter++;
  }
}
```

EDIT: as Robert pointed out, it's much better to "use" just the pins you need (in this case, bit 5 of port B and D) rather than setting the whole port; this way you minimize the risk of screwing up something else. This edit is already included in the above code, so the code is correct

Comment: Better answer, indeed. To ruin potentially less settings you can use DDRC register. You need to save its' state when assigning myportreg in your example and use the value when actually writing to port.

Comment: @RobertNavado I agree with you for using the port C, but usually when I have to use port manipulation is because I need eight bits all together. I did not understand what you meant with "save its state when assigning and use the value when writing".

Comment: You may not to want use all available bits and not all packages include all 8 bits for each port. Part may be configured differently. Sometimes you need to set 3 bits simultaneously and digital bitwise write is too slow. I can find several reasons for this. There is DDRx register for each port and you may use it for safety. You don't have to. IMHO generic and complete answer should regard this.

Comment: @RobertNavado you may use DDRx registers for... What? DDRx registers are for setting the direction (each 1 in the byte is a pin set as output, each 0 is an input). I changed the code to just set the required pin direction, instead of the whole port, but you can't use DDRx register as a replacement or "more secure version" of PORTx. I agree that you should only use the pins you need, and I'm going to specify it in the answer, but is this what you meant?

Comment: You can read it and not to set bits not configured for writing.

Comment: @RobertNavado ok, I modified the code to reflect this (which is totally reasonable: modify only what you use). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The port is a bit in one particular register. If you know the register and the position of the port in that particular register you can try this:

```
register = (1<<port) || register
```

to set the port to 1 and

```
register = (1<<port)^-1 && register
```

to set the port to 0.

Of course, you will need a switch somewhere to determine the register and the bit of the port in the register given the port name.